# Transparently insert temporary into caller's scope

Tags: c++

In C++, `operator->` has special semantics, in that if the returned type isn't a pointer, it will call `operator->` again on that type. But, the intermediate value is kept as a temporary by the calling expression. This allows code to detect changes in the returned value:

```
template<class T>
class wrapper
{
    // ...
    T val;

    struct arrow_helper
    {
        arrow_helper(const T& temp)
            : temp(temp){}
        T temp;
        T* operator->() { return &temp; }
        ~arrow_helper() { std::cout << "modified to " << temp << '\n'; }
    };

    arrow_helper operator->() { return{ val }; }
    //return const value to prevent mistakes
    const T operator*() const { return val; }
}
```

and then `T`'s members can be accessed transparently:

```
wrapper<Foo> f(/*...*/);
f->bar = 6;
```

Is there anything that could go wrong from doing this? Also, is there a way to get this effect with functions other than `operator->`?

EDIT: Another issue I've come across is in expressions like

```
f->bar = f->bar + 6;
```

since when the `arrow_helper` from the second `operator->` is destructed it re-overwrites the value back to the original. My semi-elegant solution is for `arrow_helper` to have a `T orig` that is hidden, and `assert(orig == *owner)` in the destructor.

Answer (score 3):

There is no guarantee that all changes will be caught:

```
Foo &x = f->bar;
x = 6; /* undetected change */
```

Comment: Good point, though considering [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9527820/603688) I'm not sure if there's a way to avoid that besides a comment saying not to. I think this ends up also being UB because you're referring to a temporary that has been destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no way to grab a reference to any data within `T` through `T`'s interface or otherwise, I think this should be safe. If there's any way to grab such a pointer or reference, you're done and in undefined behavior as soon as someone saves off such reference and uses it later.